# Visual Studio Force Library Import C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, linker

I have two Visual Studio C++ projects, that generate the following outputs:

```
L.lib
E.exe
```

I would like to add a dependency between *E.exe* and *L.lib*, without actually calling any methods exported from *L.lib*.  *L.lib* exports a single function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) unsigned foo();
```

Then in E.exe, I have the following compilation unit:

```
// L.cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "L.lib")
extern unsigned foo();
```

The issue is that since `foo` is unused by *E.exe*, the dependency on *L.lib* is optimized away.  What is the best way to force the dependency on *L.lib*, without actually executing any code?  The best that I could come up with is the following (appended to *L.cpp* from above):

```
__declspec(dllexport) decltype(&foo) bar{ foo };
```

However, the above results in generating additional files (*E.lib*, among others) during the linking process, and adds public methods to the EXPORTS table of the resulting *E.exe* executable.  Can anyone think of a better way to force an entry into the EXPORTS table?

I know that I could disable the linker optimization to remove unused code, but that would affect the entirety of *E.exe*, which I don't want to do.

**MORE INFORMATION**

The issue that I am seeing is that *E.exe* has a transitive dependency on a third-party *L.lib* (and associated *L.dll*) which is non-relocatable (e.g., linked with the `/FIXED` option).  By the time *L.dll* is loaded, the fixed memory address it is required to be loaded at has been taken by other DLL's loaded by *E.exe*.  I need a way to ensure that *L.dll* is loaded as early as possible, to prevent another DLL from taking the memory addresses that *L.dll* requires in order to function properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While MSalters answer works in 90% of cases, it failed to always add a reference to *L.lib* from *E.exe*.  In addition, his edited suggestion requires modifying the body of a function that is used by the executable.  I was looking for a solution that only required including an additional source file (compilation unit) sent to the linker.

After further investigation, I determined that the following code does exactly that:

```
// L.cpp
#pragma comment(lib, "L.lib")
extern "C" unsigned foo();
#pragma comment(linker, "/include:_foo")
```

This forces you to know the mangled name of `foo`, but it my case that was easy to determine due to the `extern "C"` declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Just take the address of `foo` in a way that can't be optimized out: `auto volatile pFoo = &foo;`. It's not actually called, but the compiler can't prove it's not called so it has to play it safe.

[edit]
Visual Studio is apparently more aggressive than I thought, with LTCG. Adding `pFoo=pFoo;` fixes it. Linker map: `0003:0000037c       ?pFoo@@3R6AXXZA            0040337c`

Comment: This solution works in the vast majority of my projects.  However, it still fails in a project that contains about 4 lines of code, and uses `wmain` instead of `main`.  Any other ideas as to how to trick the compiler in this instance?

Comment: @JeffG; `wmain` is a red herring. That's a level of detail the linker really doesn't care about. Also, I have no idea what  "it fails" means. Is `pFoo` not a pointer to `foo`? If it is, then `foo` must have been loaded.

Comment: *it fails* means that the VS2015 linker is still figuring out that `pFoo` isn't used, and is therefore not adding a reference to *L.lib* from the resulting *E.exe*.  I verified that regardless of whether I use main or wmain, the result is the same (the linker is optimizing out `pFoo`).